# Common class to few forms

Tags: vb.net

I find nice code for making form semi transparent while moving.
I have multiproject solution where one project is common for all other and compiles to dll which is referenced for all projects.
Code for making a form semitransparent is needed for few forms in every project but not for all forms.

I have problem on where and how to use this code to be used for certain forms.
This is a code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class clsTransForm
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private _OpacityResize As Double = 0.5
Private _OpacityMove As Double = 0.5
Private _OpacityOriginal As Double
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Long = &HA1
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Long = &HA0
Private Const WM_MOVING As Long = &H216
Private Const WM_SIZE As Long = &H5

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Static LButtonDown As Boolean

    If CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN Then
        LButtonDown = True
    ElseIf CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCLBUTTONUP Then
        LButtonDown = False
    End If

    If LButtonDown Then
        If CLng(m.Msg) = WM_MOVING Then
            If Me.Opacity <> _OpacityMove Then
                _OpacityOriginal = Me.Opacity
                Me.Opacity = _OpacityMove
            End If
        ElseIf CLng(m.Msg) = WM_SIZE Then
            If Me.Opacity <> _OpacityResize Then
                _OpacityOriginal = Me.Opacity
                Me.Opacity = _OpacityResize
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf Not LButtonDown Then
        If Me.Opacity <> _OpacityOriginal Then Me.Opacity = _OpacityOriginal
    End If
    MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
End Sub

Public Property OpacityMove() As Double
... etc...

Public Property OpacityResize() As Double
... etc...
```

I try to make a class clsTransForm under my common project but that creates me a new form.

How to configure this class for be used for just some forms?
Where and how to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making `clsTransForm` abstract by marking it as `MustInherit`. Then, in your other forms, inherit from `clsTransForm` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. Every form that inherits from `clsTransform` will have the transparency effect.

As for where to put the file itself: it doesn't matter. Just don't forget to add a project reference to the project that contains `clsTransForm` in every project that needs to use it.

Comment: Hi Steven, sounds interesting. I already have reference to place for common code. Where and how would I "marking it as MustInherit"?

Comment: Change the class definition to `Public MustInherit Class clsTransForm`. It's not required. But because `clsTransForm` is just an empty form, you will never want to instantiate it. Making it abstract mostly just helps to remind you that you have to inherit from it.

Comment: Understand. I would like to get rid of those form which IDE makes by himself. Now, I declared class as MustInherit, change in my working form's designer that it inherits from clsTransForm and now I get form opened in taskbar but is invisible. Maybe is too transparent? :) So I set Me.Opacity = 1 in main form_Load)..., don't helps. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, ok, I get it! Thank you very much for this help. I didn't know for that.

Comment: Btw, maybe you know... What if I would have need to inherit two or more classes in two or more files to a main form?

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not possible in VB.NET. That's what interfaces are for. Or you can use a decorator pattern (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for more advanced scenarios.

Comment: That look complicated. Anyway, question is theoretically. Just to keep you informed on main question... I can't use MustInherit because of error: "The designer must create an instance of type 'xcommon.clsTransForm' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.". Without MustInherit everything work as expected.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Do you have a form that is a direct instance of `clsTransForm`?

Comment: Yes I have it. It appears by himself when I create a class and I can't remove it out.